# Rest service accessible in Browser not in Java code

Tags: java, rest

I have created a restful webservice hosted on server A.
I'm trying to call this service using a Java class in a client's vpn environment. The service on hitting from the code shows me error as **Connection Refused** but is accessible on calling in browser.

The same service I try to access from public internet with the same code, it works fine.

I'm using `URLConnection` to call the service in Java code.
Also tried to apply below code but didn't help.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
```

What can be the possible reasons for that? Any Suggestions?

**Edit : Code Attached**

```
private final String crlf = "\r\n";
    private String url;
    private String boundary;
    private final int bufferSize = 4096;

    public UploadFiles(String argUrl) {
        url = argUrl;
        System.out.println(url);
        logEntry(url);
        boundary = "---------------------------4664151417711";
    }

    public int post() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String param = "value";
        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.
        String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        try (
                OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);) {

            File fileDir = new File(HomeController.configBean.getFilePath());
            File[] listFiles = fileDir.listFiles();

            for (File file : listFiles) {
                // Send text file.
                writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textFile\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF); // Text file itself must be saved in this charset!
                writer.append(CRLF).flush();
                Files.copy(file.toPath(), output);
                output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
                writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.
            }
            // End of multipart/form-data.
            writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UploadFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

// Request is lazily fired whenever you need to obtain information about response.
        int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(responseCode); // Should be 200

        return responseCode;
    } // post() method
```

**Edit 2 : Error**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown S
ource)
        at testfileupload.UsingURLConnection.uploadFilesUsingURLConnecton(UsingU
RLConnection.java:42)
        at testfileupload.FormUploadTestController.lambda$0(FormUploadTestContro
ller.java:62)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
ositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Bu
ttonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
kinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
kinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.h
andleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
ositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEve
nt$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Quantum
Toolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Glas
sViewEventHandler.java:416)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.ja
va:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Edit 3 :**

I'm getting this connection refused error at  `OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();`

**Edit 4 :**

I even tried the following code to add proxy.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", url.getHost()); // My restful service url hostname
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", url.getPort()); // My restful service url port
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please suggest.

Comment: `Accept` header, ...network, ... almost everything else

Comment: I would recommend using `RestTemplate` though.

Comment: Can you please share the exact exception and a sample of your code?

Comment: will you put your working code , Like the URL that you are accessing from the browser and how you are trying to connect using java.net.URL.

Comment: @Hades please see the edit for code.

Comment: @xerx593 Can you please me with the code to accept network?

Comment: `connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");` (try this first, the rest are "different (unknown)  things")

Comment: @xerx593 Using accept didn't solve the issue. :( Same error again. Attached the error log.

Comment: Is there maybe a required proxy that is configured in your browser but not in your Java App?

Comment: @Sebastian I'm facing challenge in calling it from a client's VM. Won't know about their proxy settings. Can we write some java code to get that and match it into the code.

Comment: On clients VM... Could be anything network related then. Proxy, Firewall, Blocked ports... I'd try to ask the client about their infrastructure.

Comment: @HarshitaSethi Please see my answer let me know if it works

Comment: @HarshitaSethi is it doesn't still add the code to close the connection and try with sample API like google url to see if it works.

Comment: Check if there's proxy setup in browser and not setup in your application.

Comment: @Sebastian please see edit 4..

Comment: @Santosh please see edit 4..

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Postman sample API its working fine for me printing 200

```
public void UploadFiles(String argUrl) {
    url = argUrl;
    System.out.println(url);
    boundary = "---------------------------4664151417711";
}

public static void main(String...strings) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String param = "value";
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.
    String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://postman-echo.com/post").openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    try { 
        OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);

        File fileDir = new File("C:\\Test");
        File[] listFiles = fileDir.listFiles();

        for (File file : listFiles) {
            // Send text file.
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textFile\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF); // Text file itself must be saved in this charset!
            writer.append(CRLF).flush();
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), output);
            output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
            writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.
        }
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode); // Should be 200
    if(connection!=null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Harshita Sethi :- You need to close the connection , let me know if it works for you.

Comment: There is no method called `disconnect()` for URLConnection.

Comment: He is using HttpURLConnection class where you are using URLConnection class. Please change to HttpUrlConnection importing java.net.HttpURLConnection

Comment: I guess you meant the opposite .. and the classes belong to the same package it's better to use httpurl connection when dealing with http request.

Comment: @Vigneshwaran please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920419/difference-between-urlconnection-httpurlconnection-and-httpsurlconnection

Comment: I asked her to use HttpUrlConnection.